# Kotlin - How to convert String to ByteArray

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin

I am trying to convert `String` to `ByteArray` in Kotlin.

In Java we can convert using `getBytes()` method.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
val testVal = "Good Morning"
val bytes = testVal.toByteArray()
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `String.toByteArray()`

extension: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-byte-array.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use this too - JSON string:

```
val payLoad = "{\"Hello \":\"Paris\",\"countryCode\":\"FR\"}"
val byteArray = payLoad.encodeToByteArray()
```

Comment: Yes on Kotlin/Native there is no .toByteArray (only on JVM), you have to use this and the only encoding is UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val checkString = "Good Morning"
        val byteString = checkString.toByteArray()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use .toByteArray() function on a string and the compiler will convert it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private function:

```
private fun stringToByteArray(texte: String): ByteArray {
   val result: kotlin.Array<Byte> = arrayOf()
   var i = 0
   for (c in texte.toCharArray()) {
      result[i++] = c.code.toByte()
   }
   return result.toByteArray()
}
```